# Are my services valued enough at my current job?

Tags: salary

I feel like I'm underpaid at my current job and I question the value of my services. This is my first time working at a job like this but I've had experience with that sort of activity  while volunteering in a technology center. Here is the details:

I'm currently a CS Student (second year) who is employed in a company that provides programming lessons for kids (ages 10-14).

I teach Python, Java, JavaScript and visual coding using Minecraft Education. The material for the sessions is provided by the employer and most of the lessons are held using Zoom for about an hour each. This are group sessions with about 5 to 8 kids in a group.

My job is to advance in the curriculum by one lesson each session and answer any questions raised in the WhatsApp groups.
The jobs requires some skill in programming languages and general understanding of computer technology to properly execute the session.

I'm getting paid *17.30$* for an hour of session time, while any other activity (including preparations) is not calculated towards my salary.
If my calculations are correct, the company makes in *5,500$* average for each course which lasts for 24 sessions, one session per week.
This means my total revenue from a course is *415$*, which is *7.5%* of their profit.
Usually, I work 18 hours in a month.

Is this percentage is enough payment for my work, considering that even 3 hours of consecutive sessions are strongly exhaustive and feel like an 8 hour shift?

How do I find my value as an asset and determine If I'm getting paid enough?

p.s: Even though it is pocket money, I am very dedicated to this work and the quality of the lessons is important to me.

Comment: *How do I find my value as an asset and determine If I'm getting paid enough?* - you're worth what people are willing to pay. Find another job and see how much of a difference in pay that would be.

Comment: @littleadv 's comment is the correct answer to your question. Your estimate of your salary as a percentage of their profit is almost certainly an overestimate of their profit. You seem to assume that your salary is the only expense. In truth they had to pay for the development of the materials you use, run registration, pay for marketing, pay for bookeeping and permitting etc. I appreciate that being 'on' for three hours is exhausting, but moving wheelbarrows full of gravel is exhausting too, and those folks still only get paid an hour's pay for an hour's work.

Comment: For what it's worth, I had a job over the summer about 4 years ago that was essentially identical to what you seem to be describing, as a community education course for teaching kids coding through Minecraft. The ages were a bit younger in my job, and the classes a bit longer, but if its any consolation, my pay was about $12.50 per hour. I have no idea if I was being paid fairly at the time, and I did it mostly for the experience as it was only a temporary position. I also keep in mind that education in general pays less than is deserved, due to funding gaps, but that's a separate topic lol ;)

Comment: Yes, you're being exploited. But no, don't think you can improve this because they'll find another College student to do the same job. Find a job elsewhere, or try to provide lessons without going through an intermediary. Those are your two best options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculating labor share of revenue or employer's profit margin is too abstract for finding if you are being paid your market value. (Answering whether or not you should be paid more than your market value is an opinion, which may be why this question has votes to close it).

Instead of abstract calculations, seek local salary comparisons, through your college's career center or on the web. And as comments above suggest, the most local wage comparison can be found when you (the most local person to yourself) interview for another job.

On your other subject, unpaid preparation time is unpaid labor, which [may not be legal](https://www.dol.gov/agencies/whd/flsa/off-the-clock) if your paid and unpaid labor average out to less that the local minimum wage. Try to stop this habit if it is self-imposed. Refuse the unpaid work if it is employer-imposed.